# What is the proper way to disable screensaver and display sleep on macOS

Tags: objective-c, macos

Most of the questions on this topic are 5+ years older, some are before Swift existed, some are reported as not working anymore.

I'm making a video game and have an issue of the screensaver turning on or the display turning off from idling while using a gamepad. One of the possible solutions to this is to disable the screensaver and idle timer while the game is running. I've ran into two possible solutions to this while browsing the internet.

The first is using `beginActivityWithOptions` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`:

```
activity = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo]
      beginActivityWithOptions: NSActivityUserInitiated
      reason: @"Running a video game"];
```

paired with a call to `[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] endActivity:activity];` in `applicationWillTerminate`.
source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/power_efficiency_guidelines_osx/PrioritizeWorkAtTheAppLevel.html

Side question to this, NSActivityLatencyCritical has very little in terms of documentation, but it looks like something that should be used for a video game?

The second one is using `IOPMAssertionCreateWithName` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

```
IOPMAssertionID assertionID;
IOPMAssertionCreateWithName(kIOPMAssertionTypeNoDisplaySleep,
                            kIOPMAssertionLevelOn, CFSTR("Running a video game"), &assertionID);
```

paired with `IOPMAssertionRelease(assertionID)` call in `applicationWillTerminate`.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1340/_index.html

What is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: Ask not what Swift can do for you.  Ask what Apple Script can do for the app.

Comment: It looks like `beginActivityWithOptions` is a high level wrapper around `IOPMAssertionCreateWithName`.

Comment: @Willeke Unless I'm doing something wrong, beginActivityWithOptions disabled the application AppNap but the screensaver and standby were not disabled, however IOPMAssertionCreateWithName disabled both

Comment: Are `beginActivityWithOptions` and `IOPMAssertionCreateWithName` called with the same options?